# How can I move Comments menu item from root menu to submenu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, menu, comments, activeadmin

I can't find the way to do it.

I found only one page about Comments, how to turn on|off.

https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#comments

Comment: Please share your code. What you have tried or any other information? What exactly you want. Question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc you linked to shows the comment_menu can be customized, and that includes changing the parent.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was blind.